# Deriving the Forward Rate Formula from the Expectation Hypothesis

Tags: fixed-income, yield-curve, forward-rate

The Expectation Hypothesis (EH) states that the current spot yield for any of the maturities is the geometric average of current and future short rates.
$$\Big(1 + y(t=0, m=\mu) \Big)^{\mu} = \prod_{t=0}^{\mu-1}\Big(1 + y(t, m=1)\Big)$$
What are the steps to arrive from *EH* to *Forward Rate*?
Most learning resources seem to use some naive concrete 3-period example, without really showing the proper mathematical derivation from EH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with the expectation hypothesis (current spot rate is the product of all future short spot rates):
$$\Big(1+y(t=0, m = \mu)\Big)^{\mu} = \prod_{t=0}^{\mu-1}\Big(1 + y(t, m =1)\Big)$$
We then factor out the last element of the multiplication series:
$$\Big(1+y(t=0, m = \mu)\Big)^{\mu} = \prod_{t=0}^{\mu-2}\Big(1 + y(t,m=\mu-1)\Big) \cdot \Big(1 + y(t=\mu-1, m=1)\Big)$$
To finally arrive at the forward rate:
$$\Big(1 + y(t=\mu-1, m=1)\Big) = \frac{\Big(1+y(t=0, m = \mu)\Big)^{\mu}}{\prod_{t=0}^{\mu-2}\Big(1 + y(t,m=\mu-1)\Big)}$$
**Forward rate is essentially just a future spot rate.**